# get image and text from server in AutoCompleteTextView and set it to custom adapter in android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, custom-adapter

i want to get data(image and name) from server by sending text from AutoCompleteTextView and set it to custom adapter, i found one example and worked like it but the example is for setting single text only, can anyone please help me customize the code to set data in custom layout ?

```
public class SuggestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
   protected static final String TAG = "SuggestionAdapter";
   private List<String> suggestions;
   boolean iNetAvailable;
   Context context = getContext();

public SuggestionAdapter(Activity context, String nameFilter) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return suggestions.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
    return suggestions.get(index);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

            iNetAvailable = isNetworkAvaliable(context);

                    SuggestionAsyncTask jp = new SuggestionAsyncTask();
                    if (constraint != null) {

                        List<SuggestionModel> new_suggestions = jp.getParseJsonWCF(constraint.toString());
                        suggestions.clear();
                        for (int i=0;i<new_suggestions.size();i++) {
                             suggestions.add(new_suggestions.get(i).getCity());
                        }


                        filterResults.values = suggestions;
                        filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return myFilter;
}
```

}

**row_layout is**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.search"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/search_friend_img_friend_pic"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_user_list_image_height_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_user_list_image_height_width"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_pic_normal_small"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/custom_user_list_comment_layout_margin_left"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search_friend_img_friend_pic"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_friend_txt_friend_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="@dimen/custom_user_list_comment_text_size"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_comment_list_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/custom_user_list_comment_date_text_size"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**SuggestionAsyntask.java**

```
public class SuggestionAsyncTask {

public SuggestionAsyncTask() {
    super();
}

}

public List<SuggestionModel> getParseJsonWCF(String sName){
    List<SuggestionModel> ListData = new ArrayList<SuggestionModel>();

    String webUrl = Constant.URL_SEARCH;

    try{
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs
                .add(new BasicNameValuePair("keyword", sName));

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(webUrl);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);    

        JSONArray data = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jobj = data.getJSONObject(i);


            ListData.add(new SuggestionModel(jobj.getString("name")));


        }

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
     return ListData;

    }
```

}

Comment: you are using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` which only single text view make your custom xml file for your layout with image and textview and inflate it

Comment: @KaranMer : sir, i have created my layout i have mentioned in question, but i don't know how to inflate it in above code

Comment: you need to replace `super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);` with `super(context, R.layout.you_customrow.xml);` in your `SuggestionAdapter` constructorand make sure it is placed in layout folder in your project.

Comment: also you need to add `getView()` method to adapter

Comment: @KaranMer : thank you sir, i got the solution by your suggestion.